# Ignore the revision of a file with SVN

Tags: svn, ignore, revision

Our project is distributed in several folders. Each folder is a kind of sub-project. I know how to get the highest revision number of each "sub-project".

```
svn info $1 | grep "Last Changed Rev" | cut -d" " -f4
```

Don't try to propose me to change the structure of this project in SVN: it's impossible. I can't use revision stored in files (executables or other).

When I install our project on a customer site, I must know the version of each sub-project installed. 
I plan to generate, locally, a file (called *version.vrs*) which will contain the highest revision number of the sub-project root directory. Theses files will be copied as well on customer sites.

Periodically, this batch file will compare the current highest revision number of a sub-project with the revision number stored in *version.vrs*. If it's different, the *version.vrs( will be updated.
If I commit this file in SVN (so that my colleagues will be able to retrieve it on their computer), this will increment the revision number. And so, when the process will check next time its contents with the highest revision number of the sub-project, the *version.vrs* file will be updated... and so on.

In the batch file used to generate the *version.vrs*, I would like to check if the last modification in a subproject is the consequence of the commitment of the *version.vrs* file. If so, I will ignore the revision number and the *version.vrs* will not be updated.

Do you have any idea how to do ?

Comment: Why you want to store `*.vrs` in repo? This is **The Bad Idea (tm)**! Can you use Win-only toys?

Comment: Just because team members need this file too. They install projects from the lastest version of SVN from their computer. So, regarding to the process, to be sure the *.vrs files are installed too, they must have them. I did not explain all details and contraints about our implementation, 'cause it's not the subject of my question.

Comment: If they want these files, they can build and store they locally. Lazyness is bad! Anyway, it's task for your deploy tool **without storing in SVN already existing data**